# Random Number: either 0 or 1

Tags: c, random

I've this code:

```
srand(time(NULL));
int n = rand() % 1 + 0;
printf("%d\n", n);
```

But, if i put it (not`srand(time(NULL))`) in a loop for e.g., it generates only a sequence of 0.
There is another implementation for the random numbers between 0 and 1 or i've forgot something?

Comment: rand() % 1 is always 0, because what rand returns is always divisible by 1

Comment: by the way + 0 always adds 0, and therefore has no effect here.

Comment: if that's about getting 0 1 in a random way, and the target OS has arc4random implementation (either in libc or in a package), it could be arc4random_uniform(2) calls

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you meant 0 *or* 1, your `%` makes some sense, but you meant `% 2` (or `& 1`). Of course, the `+ 0` is still rather pointless, no idea what you're aiming for there. For an integer result of 0 or 1, just do:

```
const randomBit = rand() % 2;
```

The compiler will probably ["strength-reduce"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction) that to:

```
const randomBit = rand() & 1;
```

Also, make sure you only call `srand()` *once* in your program or it won't have the effect you expect.

Comment: No no i don't want float values, i only want 0 or 1!

Comment: on some platforms there is "warning: rand() may return deterministic values, is that what you want?"

Answer (score 11):

If you want either 0 or 1, just do

```
int n = rand() % 2
```

if what rand returns is even you'll get a 0, and if it's odd you'll get a 1 here.

Answer (score 1):

```
int n = rand() % 1 + 0;
```

will produce `0` always as `rand() % 1` gives `0` (`rand()%a` generates number between `0` to `a-1`).

Comment: Yes srand(time(NULL)); is out of the loop, i was referring to the other two instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is an issue, because calling rand() is relatively slow, you can call it only once every 31 value you need, and use bit-shifting to access each bit (0 or 1) of the 31-bit random number returned by each rand() call. (The 32nd bit is the sign bit, always 0 since it's a positive integer.)

On my MacBook the following code runs 29 times faster (0.74 s) when using the bit-shifting line compared to the one calling rand() each time (21.45 s).

```
int main() {
    int i, j, r, x=0;
    srand(37843284);
    for(i=0;i<100000000;i++) {
        r = rand();
        for(j=0;j<31;j++) {
            x+=(r>>j)&1; // bit-shifting
            //x+=rand()&1; // call rand() each time
        }
    }
    printf("%i", x);
    return 0;
}
```

The "call rand() each time" solution could be made faster using other algorithms, e.g., [Mersenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/C-LANG/c-lang.html). Also, this solution might be machine-dependent, works if RAND_MAX==2^31-1.

Answer (score -1):

```
std::srand(time(0)); //Randomise seed initialisation
for (int rows = 0; rows < n; rows++) {
    int randNum = rand() % 2;
}
```